# What does the Combinatorica function: NumberOfPermutationsByType return?

Tags: functions, combinatorics, permutation, combinatorica

I am using *Mathematica 9*.
If I input:

```
NumberOfPermutationsByType[{2, 2, 1, 1}]
```

*Mathematica* returns `1/8`.
I was expecting `45`, the number of permutations of `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` with cycle lengths `2,2,1,1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of a permutation of length $n$ is $\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n\}$ where $\lambda_i$ is the number of cycles of length $i$. Therefore, the number of permutations of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ that have two 1-cycles and two 2-cycles is

```
NumberOfPermutationsByType[{2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0}]

(* 45 *)
```

The best reference for *Combinatorica* is Steven Skiena's [book](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~skiena/combinatorica/), in particular [section 3.1.2 (page 99)](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ib80AAAAQBAJ&pg=PR58) shows the actual implementation of this function:

```
NumberOfPermutationsByType[l_List] := 
                (Length[l]!)/Apply[Times, Table[l[[i]]!i^(l[[i]]), {i, Length[l]}]]
```